# How to access specific links in one div?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to access the second link within this div (the div has numerous links within it):

```
[<div class="tabs standard-box"><a class="stats-top-menu-item stats-top-menu-item-link" data-link-tracking-column="[Main content]" data-link-tracking-destination="Click on Overview [subnavigation]" data-link-tracking-page="Matchstats" href="/stats/teams/7865/HAVU">Overview</a><a class="stats-top-menu-item stats-top-menu-item-link selected" data-link-tracking-column="[Main content]" data-link-tracking-destination="Click on Matches [subnavigation]" data-link-tracking-page="Matchstats" href="/stats/teams/matches/7865/HAVU">Matches</a><a class="stats-top-menu-item stats-top-menu-item-link" data-link-tracking-column="[Main content]" data-link-tracking-destination="Click on Maps [subnavigation]" data-link-tracking-page="Matchstats" href="/stats/teams/maps/7865/HAVU">Maps</a><a class="stats-top-menu-item stats-top-menu-item-link" data-link-tracking-column="[Main content]" data-link-tracking-destination="Click on Players [subnavigation]" data-link-tracking-page="Matchstats" href="/stats/teams/players/7865/HAVU">Players</a><a class="stats-top-menu-item stats-top-menu-item-link" data-link-tracking-column="[Main content]" data-link-tracking-destination="Click on Event history [subnavigation]" data-link-tracking-page="Matchstats" href="/stats/teams/events/7865/HAVU">Event history</a><a class="stats-top-menu-item stats-top-menu-item-link" data-link-tracking-column="[Main content]" data-link-tracking-destination="Click on Lineups [subnavigation]" data-link-tracking-page="Matchstats" href="/stats/teams/lineups/7865/HAVU">Lineups</a></div>]
```

I have tried numerous method but cannot seem to access it. Trying to access "/stats/teams/matches/7865/HAVU"
(I am a newbie on python)

teammatch's output is the div above.

I have tried the following:

- `find_all('a')['href']`
- `find({'class':'stats-top-menu-item stats-top-menu-item-link')`

```
r = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'tab-content '},{'id':'TODAY'})

for result in r[1:]:
    tournament = result.find_all('div',{'class':'ongoing-event-holder'})
    link = tournament.find('a')['href']

link2 = requests.get('https://www.hltv.org' + link, headers=headers)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(link2.text,'html.parser')
team = soup2.find_all('div',{'class':'groups'})
for result1 in team:
    team1 = result1.find('div',{'class':'text-ellipsis'})
    link3 = team1.find('a')['href']

link4 = requests.get('https://www.hltv.org' + link3, headers=headers)
x = ('https://www.hltv.org' + link3) + str('#tab-statsBox')
link5 = requests.get(x, headers=headers)
soup3 = BeautifulSoup(link5.text, 'html.parser')
team_stats = soup3.find_all('div',{'class':'moreButton-container'})
for result2 in team_stats:
    teamstatlink = result2.find('a')['href']

link6 = requests.get('https://www.hltv.org' + teamstatlink, headers=headers)
soup4 = BeautifulSoup(link6.text, 'html.parser')
team_matches = soup4.find_all('div',{'class':'stats-top-menu'})
for result3 in team_matches:
    teammatch = result3.find_all('div',{'class':'tabs standard-box'})
```

the goal here is to assign link7 to the '/stats/teams/matches/7865/HAVU'

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: what is the initial full start url you are scraping from?

Comment: https://www.hltv.org/events#tab-TODAY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get all the `<a>` elements, and extract the href attribute using the `get()` method. then get the second link from the result list. it can be done in one line using list comprehension:

```
link7 = [a.get("href") for a in teammatch[0].find_all("a")][1]
```